# Cannot run PHP CLI on WAMP on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wamp, php

I have been trying on this for hours 
i Get the below error

`'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Steps i have done
1- I have added to Windows Environement variables `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13;`
2-re-installed wamp 2 times
3-Apache and php error log is clean

I have the below configuration

1. Windows 8 64 bit
2. Apache 2.2
3. PHP 5.3.13

Comment: Open 'cmd' and type 'php' to see if it's in system path.

Comment: use the full path to the binary on wamp its something like c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.4/bin/php.exe

Comment: I have changed path to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe;` and still same error @Dave

@IgorS. already got error as described above

Comment: @AhmedSamy The PATH item must be a directory, not a file. Change it to: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13` Also, I believe you need to restart Windows for it to take effect.

Comment: If he's referencing the file directly (including full path) as above then it should work fine it'll only fail if you don't get the environment setup correct and try doing just php-cli.exe but if you do fullpath/php-cli.exe it should be fine (unless its not installed in that location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that `php-cli.exe` dosent come along with WAMP, I installed XAMPP instead and CLI worked perfectly

Comment: The PHP CLI is in `c:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.Y.Z\php.exe`

Answer (score 3):

Actually the php exe you run in wamp for the CLI is just php.exe

It is found in the c\wamp\bin\php\phpX.Y.Z\ folder and called php.exe

Suggest you create a little batch file to setup the path so you can use it from anywhere by just keying php, like this:

phppath.cmd

```
set path=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.Y.Z
php -v
```

Store this batch file in a folder on your path and you are golden.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add php to your system path as follows:

- go to system properties
- chooose advance tab
- check the system variables
- choose Path then edit it and add at the end  ;C:\xampp\php\

Note that system variables in Path are separated with **;**
same thing applies to WAMP all you need is to specify your php binaries folder