# Cygwin Console : Can't Execute PHP Scripts Locally In Command Line

Tags: php, cygwin, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to run a php script locally placed under wamp folder in cygwin command line but getting the following error -
"-bash: php: command not found"

The Local Server I am using is WAMP.
The php.exe file is in the path C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.24
and I am using cygwin in windows 10.

Any suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Ritaja

Comment: either use a full path `/cygdrive/c/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.24/php.exe` or add the directory to your cygwin environment

Comment: Just **never** add the path to PHP into your Windows PATH

Comment: Or run the script from a window command window

Comment: Thanks, I have tried running the command from windows console but it has thrown an error - 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16246862/2310830