# Wamp64 doesn't detect the change of php version (5 to 7)

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, wampserver, php-7

well my problem is this:

I have a Laravel project and if you don't know, Laravel needs php 7.

Wamp64 give me the option to choose my php version 5.6.31, 7.0.23 or 7.1.9. When i select the 7.0.23 o 7.1.0 and run the command composer installl, it shows me the error that my php version is the 5.6.31 and i need a >=7.0.0
I checked the phpinfo() and it show 7.1.9
Why does this happened?

EDIT:
Also i have XAMPP with php5, but it's not active. It could be the Version of XAMPP the cause of the problem?

Comment: is `composer installl`  run on the command line?

Comment: yes, i run on the command line

Comment: what will be why, you wuill need to suply the path to correct php version to use.

Comment: i checked the htttp.conf file of apache and it says the module is from php7

Comment: command line php, and the version the Apache server is using may not be the same

Comment: oh yeah, you are right. When i run php -v it show me PHP 5.6.31, then how can i change it?

Comment: I guess you have solve the  issue @DanCruz

Comment: Are you using the windows command prompt or do you have something like GitBash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166457/cannot-run-php-cli-on-wamp-on-windows-8/16246862#16246862

Comment: Or a more comprehensive answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254